# Problems adding fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I am using fragments in my **Xamarin** based android application, but when I Add() a new fragment (even if I can see this new fragment on the screen), if I touch the screen I can see that the listener of the old fragment are still working.

I have two fragment. fragment1 is a listView, fragment2 shows the details of the entities present in fragment1. Clicking on an item of this listView a new fragment (fragment2) will be added on the screen. But even if I can see fragment2, if I click on the screen a third fragment is added on the screen because the listener of the fragment1 is still active.

How can I fix this problem?

This if the function that I use to change fragment:

```
private void ChangeFragment (TitledFragment newFragment, string fragmentTitle)
        {
            if (newFragment is IPrimaryFragment) {
                _drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = true;
                _drawer.SetDrawerLockMode (DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
                _displayingPrimaryFragment = true;
                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ().Replace (Resource.Id.content_frame, newFragment).Commit ();
                if (_currentFragment != null)
                    _currentFragment.Cleanup ();
            } else {
                _drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;
                _drawer.SetDrawerLockMode (DrawerLayout.LockModeLockedClosed);
                _displayingPrimaryFragment = false;
                SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction ().Add (Resource.Id.content_frame, newFragment).AddToBackStack (null).Commit ();
            }

            if (fragmentTitle != null)
                newFragment.Title = fragmentTitle;

            ActionBar.Title = newFragment.Title;

            _currentFragment = newFragment;
        }

        public override bool OnKeyUp (Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (keyCode == Keycode.Menu) {
                if (_drawer.IsDrawerOpen (GravityCompat.Start))
                    _drawer.CloseDrawer (GravityCompat.Start);
                else
                    _drawer.OpenDrawer (GravityCompat.Start);
                return true;
            }
            if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
                if (_displayingPrimaryFragment) {
                    DialogUtils.ShowDialog (this, GetString (Resource.String.do_you_really_want_to_exit), null, true, GetString (Resource.String.yes), GetString (Resource.String.no), () => base.Finish (), () => {} );
                    return true;
                } else {
                    SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate ();
                    _currentFragment = (TitledFragment) SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById (Resource.Id.content_frame);
                    if (_currentFragment is IPrimaryFragment) {
                        _displayingPrimaryFragment = true;
                        _drawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = true;
                        _drawer.SetDrawerLockMode (DrawerLayout.LockModeUnlocked);
                    }
                    ActionBar.Title = _currentFragment.Title;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return base.OnKeyUp (keyCode, e);
        }
```

By now fragment2 is simply a empty layout..this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pnlMain"
    android:background="#ffffff" />
```

Comment: +1 for proper formatting in first question.

Comment: The only way this could be happening is if you set your touch listener on the fragment container rather than on something in the fragment itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your details fragment setOnTouchListener to get view() and return true.

I assume that the details fragment is overlayed on top of the list fragment and since detail is empty and doesn't consume any touch events, it gets propagated into your list fragment.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! :)
I do not think that this is something "normal", the android framework should do this automatically...but android is android and we know it xD.

Thanks again!